# how to prevent Web scrapers/crawlers/bots to hit my API

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping

I'm new to Stack overflow. I have a API developed in Flask Python 3. I am calling that API from front end.

I need to give the response for only 3 requests from that browser/IP/whatever the best way to detect that user and on the 4th requests i need to throw error that your limit exceeded.

How can i achieve this to identify the user is same user and clock them permanently till he signups.

- Front end: html and ajax request
- Back-end : pyhton3 and flask

I'm able to get the ip address by below method

```
@app.route('/api/givedata', methods=['GET'])
def givedata():
    return jsonify({'ip': request.remote_addr}), 200
```

But, some scraping guys may use VPN and other things to access. How to prevent these data crawlers/Bots?

Comment: If you have a question about python, why have you tagged it with PHP and jquery?

Comment: agreed this appears not to be related to php or jquery in any way at all.

Comment: Anyway: _"How can i achieve this to identify the user is same user"_ ...short answer: authentication. Make them sign up for a trial account. Then if they want to use it more you can convert it to a full account.

Comment: _"Any wrong posting in this question which are not in the guidelines. Please forgive"_ ...well there's nothing much wrong with this post as it happens, but equally you would have less problems if you take the time to read the guidelines before posting. I can see from your profile (due to the missing "Informed" badge) that you didn't take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) yet, despite this being recommended when you created your account.

Comment: So I guess if you didn't do that, then you maybe also didn't explore the Help section, and didn't read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Those would be the minimum required reading of the guidelines. If you don't know what's in the guidelines, then clearly you will be more likely to have trouble sticking to them.

Comment: Am sorry. But, if same user is hitting my API with incognito windows and other stuff.. how can i tackle it

Comment: Like I said before, make them authenticate to use the API. That's the only reliable way. See my comment above which starts "Anyway..."